# It's about the traction and engine power reduced issue

Tags: pontiac, power-loss, g6

I have 2006 Pontiac G6 hardtop convertible. The car's service traction message and engine power reduced and car doesn't accelerate properly. Any ideas that I can try to resolve this problem without putting in shop?

I tried resetting computer seemed to run great for about two miles or so then service traction message and engine power reduced message was displayed could feel the rpms drop and car had no power

Comment: No workaround, you will have to have the car diagnosed and repaired.

Comment: Please need help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Any codes to report?

Comment: the fact that the message and the accompanying limp mode returned after being reset indicates that this isn't a transient issue. You'll have to get the error codes read (or read them yourself with an OBD-II reader) to get an idea of what the issue is. It *may* be something you can DIY but there's no way to be sure without more info.